# Name collision in webservice using enterprise application, Weblogic 12

Tags: web-services, weblogic12c

I have a web application that is using (calling) two identical webservices, they only differ in URL. I use Netbeans 8 to generate the webservice clients, both of which are in the same separate project but in two separate packages. The main application packages everything in a super jar.
Deploying the super jar to Weblogic causes a JAXBException, name collision. The relevant part of the error message:
Two classes have the XML type with uri http://yet.another/useless/namespace/url and name fault.
All of the classes have identical names, yet it's the one with the name fault that is bothering Weblogic.
I could totally separate these web services into different enterprise applications of course but that seems like overkill.
I read the WSDLs from a remote server and don't really have a chance to convince our contractor to change namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I just worked around it: I'm using Axis2 to generate client side code as I'm free to perform whatever refactoring is necessary on it to avoid name collisions. Morale of the story: Avoid IDE wizards (if they cause trouble).